# Cycles Procedural Square using Polar Coordinates

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, procedural

I'm using Blender 2.8 and trying to get a grasp on procedural textures.
For fun, I was following through the list here at https://thndl.com/square-shaped-shaders.html and now I'm stuck.

Equation I'm trying to reproduce:

```
 float a=atan(c.x,c.y);

 f=vec4(step(.5,cos( floor(a*.636+.5)* 1.57-a)*length(c.xy)))
```

Result = A Square

I have a feeling it has to do with the Polar Coordinates, but I'm not sure where considering I believe the math is correct everywhere else.

Can someone take a look and see where the mistake is and perhaps explain though it if possible?

Thanks!

Shader Node Setup:
[image]
(Length = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

The Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you've actually got wrong with your setup but I've tried to replicate it by entering your math into a Node Expressions expression (see https://baldingwizard.wixsite.com/blog/node-expressions) - which builds the nodes directly from the text.

This produces the following result :

[image: result]

The generated 'inner' nodes for the 'f' function are :

[image: inner nodes]

And here's the Blend file (Blender 2.8) for reference [image]

---

EDIT: Actually, I think I've spotted the error. Your nodes actually perform the calculation :

```
f = cos(floor(a * 0.636+0.5)*(1.57-a)) * dist
```

ie, Instead of multiplying by 1.57 and then subtracting 'a', you're nodes subtract a from 1.57 and then multiply - note the brackets I added around '1.57-a'). Here's the amended (wrong) calculation, replicating your result :

[image: incorrect calculation]

Comment: Hehe... just as i finished building the tree by hand, you nipped in before me! That'll teach me to use your kit.... Can I add 2 recommendations?

Comment: @RobinBetts Haha - sorry about that! :-) Sure can - always open to improvement.

Comment: 1. It doesn't make a difference here, but the [GLSL call](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/atan.xhtml) is of the [-pi,pi] overload of atan(), so Arctan2 node would be a better choice, further down the page the OP is looking at.  2. Blender 2.81 provides a better Vector Math node for following GLSL whole-vector operations..

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks. The addon does actually support atan2 - yes, I probably should have used it (but as you say, not relevant here since it’s a square). I must admit to not really understanding the ‘vec4’ in the original expression - is that what you mean by ‘whole-vector’ operations? What’s that doing in this case?

Comment: I don't get the vec4, either, no need for homogeneous space, here?  ... no... I meant that in GLSL you can call  floor(), abs(), etc. for element-wise operations on _vectors_, without having to split them up, there's a  built-in length(), and so on.,  and now you can do that in Blender 2.81, too..

Comment: @RobinBetts Ah - I see what you mean now. I’ve only had a brief look at 2.81 so far - sounds like there are quite a fee interesting changes. I’ll have to take a closer look and see what other functions I can include. Thanks!

Comment: @RichSedman: Thanks so much! I made the adjustment and it turned out as it should.  Also thanks for the link above! I'll be using that from now on to test.